# javascript object reference not work as expected

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Can anyone explain me what is going on in this code below? Why does it work like this? I expected the variable `a` would change too...

```
var base = {
  cars: {
    color: "blue",
    brand: "Ford"
  }
}

var a = base.cars;
base.cars = function () { console.log("example method") }

console.log(base) // changed to method
console.log(a) // still is object - why?
```

Comment: It's not clear why you expected that. You're assigning a new value to the property, but that doesn't alter any of the other references to the old value.

Comment: You're confusing it with pointers wherein changing the value using a pointer would change all the other values referenced using that pointer. Here, a new object is created and the reference of base.cars is changed but that of a remains the same.

Comment: I'm getting object object for the console logs. Are you saying you are *not* getting `object` as return result on `console.log(base)`. Im unable to reproduce your result using your exact code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are no pointers in JavaScript.

---

At the beginning, you have something like this:

```
base ---+
        |
        v
        {
          cars ----+
        }          |
                   v
                   {
                     color: "blue"
                     brand: "Ford"
                   }
                   ^
                   |
a -----------------+
```

Now both `base.cars` and `a` point to the same object.

Then, when you reassign `base.cars`, it becomes:

```
base ---+           
        |          
        v          
        {          
          cars ---> function(){ ... }
        }          
                   
                   {
                     color: "blue"
                     brand: "Ford"
                   }
                   ^
                   |
a -----------------+
```

`a` will continue to point at the object referenced by `base.cars` *at the time of the assignment*. Then, even when `base.cars` is reassigned, it doesn't affect the value (and the reference) of `a`.

---

If you were able to create a pointer, it would look like this:

```
base ---+
        |
        v
        {
          cars ----+
        } ^        |
          |        v
          |        {
          |          color: "blue"
          |          brand: "Ford"
          |        }
          |     
          |        
a --------+
```

...and after reassignment:

```
base ---+
        |
        v
        {
          cars ----> function(){ ... }
        } ^        
          |        
          |        {
          |          color: "blue"
          |          brand: "Ford"
          |        }
          |        |
          |        +--> Garbage collection
a --------+
```